# Is it a logical approach to set Page.Theme based on query string?

Tags: asp.net, themes

As I said, is it a logical approach to set page theme based on query string on page load event(in masterpage)?

For example, get **culture** from `http://mydomain.com/{cultureId}/somepage.aspx` and setting page theme based on `{cultureId}`

Comment: This is perfectly reasonable, it's exactly what MSDN does.  You could use browser settings to select a default culture, then provide a UI for the user to choose a culture.

Comment: Also, I found an example here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETEmbedLanguageInUrl-de9c06ad

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the browser settings instead, if culture is actually what you are looking for. This is available on the `request.UserLanguages` property.

If not, you could of course use some request string parameter, but, you would need to handle all links, etc, yourself, to include the correct culture.

Comment: The problem with using browser settings is that browsers don't provide a convivial and discoverable UI to change the preferred culture.  So it's better for an app to provide a way for the user to choose a culture independent of browser settings.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I think maybe I would put it in either a cookies (if you want it to vary per browser), or in a DB setting. Is it a logged-in site, btw?

Comment: Why force a user to log in or enable cookies just to choose a preferred language?

Comment: That wasn't my point. I was just asking if it was a logged-in site. If it is, it makes sense to store the user's preference server-side (in a db or something). If not, maybe the URL would make sense. But, if I, as a Norwegian user, share a page with you, wouldn't you prefer to have it in your preferred culture instead of Norwegian? So, if we embed the culture in the URL, this could be problematic.

Comment: I don't speak Norwegian, but I do speak other languages and generally prefer to see content in its original language rather than a translated version if it's a language I know.  And I like being able to switch languages on a site easily, for example it's useful to see MSDN in multiple languages so I can use consistent terminology when writing my own foreign-language documentation.  I think MSDN have it right: default to Accept-Languages preference; selected culture in the URL; UI to change languages. I agree with you that it's good to save user preferences server-side if the user's logged in.